# Cant find redeem code on starcraft 2 digital purchase

Tags: starcraft-2

Can someone help me locating the game key of the Starcraft 2 WOL i just purchased? The only email blizzard sent me was the transaction. No links or whatsoever.. I already installed the starter edition then upgrade it but redirects me to the buy link of starcraft 2. I bought it but dont know where is the redeem key.. Any help?

Comment: check your spam filter

Answer (score 2):

If you have bought the game directly on Battle.Net, there is no code to be redeemed. The game license just gets directly added to your account, which you can check at https://eu.battle.net/account/management/ (or [US site](https://us.battle.net/account/management/)).

You can then download a game client from the site, but if I recall correctly, the Starter Edition should download an update automatically, did it not?

Comment: IIRC there shouldn't be any update needed, game access should change based on which account logged in, so it should usually be enough to logout and log back in after waiting a bit.

Comment: @Mario Right you are. The game is installed completely anyway, so that any user can log in and play his respective game.